# UICollectionView and UITableView in the same ViewController with the same scroll

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have a big doubt about how could I do something like the title said.

I know that UICollectionView and UITableView are scrollable views, but I need 
that two views do scroll together (with both independent scroll desactivated).

It would be of great help to do it with storyboard if possible.

Thanks in advance!

PD: I'm working with Xamarin iOS.

Comment: yes you can add both in same viewcontroller .

Comment: yes, I know this, but need more information about how to build it with the same scroll